# Is it possible to have more than one launcher Activity?

Tags: android, android-launcher

Is it possible to have more than one application in one apk file? or is there a way to have different launcher icons for different activities inside one app? I want to separate my app into some different (but related) logical parts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, just **mark two or more of your `<activity>`s as `LAUNCHER`** within your manifest.
In addition you have to set the `android:taskAffinity` attribute on both of your Launcher-Activities which specify the exact package and Activity to be started.

```
<activity android:label="MyApp" android:name=".MyApp" android:taskAffinity="com.example.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".MyApp"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>


<activity android:label="Settings" android:name=".Settings" android:taskAffinity="com.example.SettingsActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".Settings"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: How the OS will decide, which launcher activity to trigger?

Comment: Doesn't work, both of them start the first declared Activity with action.MAIN

Comment: What actually the `android:taskAffinity` do, because it works without it.

Comment: it controls the flow between activities when the app pause/continue depending on how it was started

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can have more than one launcher activity in your application. 
This will not create any kind of compile-time or run time error. 
You will find two launcher logos of your application in your device can launch different activities as we defined in manifest.